# Through Loop specific Textboxes lines contains in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have this text file: with 4 corresponding text boxes: TxtStringNumP1, TxtStringNumP2, TxtStringNumP3 and TxtStringNumP4, I need to display the corresponding values: in Textboxes: that is, to display these values ​​(numbers) in the appropriate box. this is what my text file looks like:

```
[TxtStringNumP1]
4
5
2
4
[TxtStringNumP2]
5
10
4
6
6
5
10
```

How do I write this code to make it work?

```
Dim line As String
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Number.txt")
        ' Read one line from file
         line = reader.ReadLine
         If(line.Contains("[TxtStringNumP1]") Then
             'The current line is the store hours header, so we skip it (read the next line)         
              line = reader.ReadLine
              'Process the line like you want, and keep processing through the lines by doing a readline each time you want to progress to the next line.
         End If
End Using
```

I have to make it look like this:

`TxtStringNumP1.Text` =

```
4
5
2
4
```

`TxtStringNumP2.Text` =

```
5
10
4
6
```

Others code:

If you want to apply some logic line by line skipping the unwanted lines, then read the file line by line or process the lines one at time after reading them in memory (the choice depends on file size)

This approach uses the IEnumerable extension Where on the lines returned by ReadLines (who returns an IEnumerable of your lines and doesn't load them all in memory).

```
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(f.FullName).
                Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("Kleur"))
    ' lines contains only the lines without the word Kleur
    For Each l As String In lines
        ' Process the lines
    Next
Next
```

But you can also use a StreamReader to read a single line, process it if required, then loop for the next line

```
Dim line As String = ""
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Using sr = New StreamReader(f.FullName)
        While True
            line = sr.ReadLine
            If line IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not line.Contains("Kleur") Then
                    ' process the line
                End If
            Else
                Exit While
            End If 
        End While
    End Using
Next
```

Finally you can load everything in memory and process from there (but pay attention to the size of the file)

```
Dim line As String = ""
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.FullName)
    For each line in lines
       if Not line.Contains("Kleur") Then
         ' process the line
       End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started with a `StreamReader` so I used that approach.

I am using a `StringBuilder` to accumulate the the strings for the text boxes. A `StringBuilder` is mutable (changeable) unlike a String. Every time we add something to a String, the old String to discarded and a new string is created. If there are more than a few strings, a `StringBuilder` is more efficient.

I read the first line then start the outer `Do` loop. First we find the text box to be filled using the `Controls` collection. I strip off the leading and trailing brackets to get the string that is the name of the text box.

The inner `Do` keeps looping until we reach the end of the file or find the next occurrence of the bracket. `.ToString` is called on the `StringBuilder` and added to the text box. The `StringBuilder` is cleared and we go to the top of the outer `Do` and get the next text box.

The outer loop quits at the end of the file.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim line As String
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\TestReader.txt")
        line = reader.ReadLine
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Do
            Dim tb = CType(Controls(line.Trim("["c).Trim("]"c)), TextBox)
            Do
                If reader.Peek < 0 Then 'Check that you haven't reached the end
                    Exit Do
                End If
                line = reader.ReadLine
                If line.StartsWith("["c) Then 'Check if we have reached another check box.
                    Exit Do
                End If
                sb.AppendLine(line)
            Loop
            tb.Text = sb.ToString
            sb.Clear()
        Loop Until reader.Peek < 0
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything works so well, fast, and I can learn new things.